# What happens when onkeyup script is retriggered while running?

Tags: javascript, html

I was wondering, what happens when a button is pressed and the specified "onkeyup" script is triggered while that script is running?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: can you elaborate more or give an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have a function, that is bound to an event, and this event triggers, then this function will run as many times, as the event triggers. So if you trigger keyup event 5 times, the corresponding function will run 5 times as well.

If you want to avoid it, you should do some checkout. For example, I often do it, when work on some sliders. Here's an example:

```
$('.selector').click( function() {
    if ( ! $(this).is(':animated') ) {
        // further actions will occur, only if the ".selector" is NOT animated,
        // regardless how many times you click it.
    }
});
```